# Unchecking a radio button with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, radiobuttonfor

I have several `RadioButtonFor` (razor) and I am trying to make a JQuery script that unchecks others buttons when you check another one.

I have a model with an array of booleans to pass to the Html Helper and printer names:

```
public class Mymodel
{    
    public List<PrinterModel> printers { get; set; }
    public bool noDefault { get; set; }
}
```

My `PrinterModel` is as follows :

```
public class Printermodel
{
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public string printerName { get; set; }
}
```

Which then gives in my view, :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()
{
<div class="form-group">
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.printers.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.printers[i].selected, new { @class = "default" });
        @Html.Label(Model.printers[i].printerName);
        <br/>
    }
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.noDefaultRadio, new { @class = "noDefault", @checked= "checked" });
    @Html.Label("No default printer");
</div>
}
```

I know I can use `.prop('checked', false)` in JQuery to uncheck a radiobox, so I tried in the first play to uncheck the default button :

```
$('.default').change(function () {
    if ($('.default:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.noDefault').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.noDefault').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

This does nothing, but works for checkboxes, why?

**Also**, the `@checked="checked"` doesn't make the `RadioButtonFor` checked by default, and I've also tried `@checked = true` which doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT** When trying to use `name="default"` as suggested, I see the following input when inscpecting the page in my navigator :

```
<input data-val="true" id="printers_0__primarySelected" name="printers[0].primarySelected" type="radio" value="{ disabled = disabled }"
```

Comment: Try `.prop('selected', false)` for radio buttons

Comment: If I am not mistaken, radio buttons are meant for select one at a time. maybe you are missing any grouping ?

Comment: I don't know, what do you mean by grouping? Also, same script with selected does not do anything

Comment: shouldn't you just put the radiobuttonsfor in a div or a form ?

Comment: @Louis-RochTessier Sorry forgot to precise that it is inside a `Html.BeginForm` and in `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just make the radio buttons part of a group?  What you are trying to do sounds like default behavior.

Can you add the `name = "printerGroup"` (or similar) to your HTML attributes in the RadioButtonFor calls to group these together?

**UPDATE:**

Stepping back, sounds like you want 1 radio button to be selected.  You should be looking to have a selectedId or some identifier passed back to your controller once you submit.  I would look to make the following changes.

**Model**

```
public class PrinterModel   
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string printerName { get; set; }
    }

public class MyModel
    {
        public List<PrinterModel> printers { get; set; } = new List<PrinterModel>();
        public string selectedId { get; set; } //This will be the id of what gets selected
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.printers.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.selectedId, Model.printers[i].Id, new { name = "test" });
            @Html.Label(Model.printers[i].printerName);
            <br />
        }
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.selectedId, "0", new { name = "test" })
        @Html.Label("No default printer")
    </div>
}
```

Inside your controller you can get the selectedId and do something with it, if 0 was passed in that would be the default (change as needed).

Comment: I did put `@class="default"` if this is what you mean? Not sure I quite understand the purpose of what you propose?

Comment: When radio buttons share a common name they are treated as a group.  When grouped together only 1 radio button can be selected at a time.  So if all your radio buttons were in a group then only 1 could be selected at a time, add name = "printerGroup" to the call and see if that does what you want.

Comment: I see, so I tried : `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.printers[i].primarySelected, new { @disabled = "disabled",  Name = "default"});` but this doesn't work

Comment: All of the radio buttons need the same name, can you make sure to use lowercase name (name = "printerGroup") ?

Comment: Still not successful. When I inspect my code I do see this though : `<input name="printer[0].selected" />` and it changes for each loop, so maybe the problems comes from the Expression `m => m.printers[i].selected` ? Don't know how to fix this though, I though you had to put a boolean here, not a name?

Comment: Yeah, this works, it was the Expressions that made everything twitchy, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Use `click` instead of `change` event because once radio is checked `change` event won't trigger again.

```js
$('.default').click(function () {
    if ($('.default:checked').length > 0) {
        $('.noDefault').prop('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.noDefault').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check .default <input type="radio" name="one" class="default" /> <br/>
Check .noDefault <input type="radio" name="two" class="noDefault" checked /> <br/>
```

Comment: This does not work either :s I think my script is wrong .